# Циця в руцю, а серце в пуцю

Tags: значення-слів

Припускаю, що у тексті пісні [Зозулиця](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlGjgIk3ha4) гурта Dakh Daughters використані прислів'я, приказки та інші зразки народної творчості. На 02:54 в пісні звучить: "Циця в руцю, а серце в п(б)уцю".

Питання: чи є цей вислів прислів'ям і якщо є, то яке його значення?

Comment: У словниках не дивився, але нагуглив таку приказку: ["скільки вовка не годуй, а у медведя пуця більша і дупа ширша"](http://www.bukinfo.com.ua/show/news?lid=65540)

Comment: Ще про пуцю: «[Зі слів дівчини, що випадково побачила чоловіка голим:] Та пуця у нього нівроку — ніжна і рожевенька — в головці.» (з книги «Муха з цукром», Роман Кухарчук, 2003, [ст. 100](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22та+пуця+у+нього+нівроку+ніжна+і+рожевенька+в+головці%22)). Схоже, що в усіх цих випадках слово «пуця» має одне й те саме значення (статевий чоловічий орган). Хоча скоріше це евфемізм, а не основне значення (бо використовується [і як ім'я](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22баба+пуця%22+OR+%22бабця+пуця%22)).

Comment: @Sasha, так, це слово можна зустріти в народному (переважно сільському) фольклорі/жартах (почасти поза літературними нормами) саму в цьому значенні. Щодо тлумачення змісту, а головно - моралі, власне приказки, то припускаю, що означає вона таке: щойно чоловік торкається жінки, особливо її принад, то його емоції й розум перемикаються на інстинкти (ще кажуть: "Думає не головою, а "одним місцем").

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, дуже цікава думка, мені здається, що Ви не далеко від істини. Хоча якщо припустити, що наведене Вами тлумачення вірне, то "розум в пуцю" був би більш доречним.

Comment: @Gluttton, то вже варіації, на мою думку. Я написала "емоції й розум перемикаються", бо люди схильні наділяти серце невластивими йому функціями (відповідальність за емоції, почуття), що не є правильним з наукової точки зору, бо насправді серце - це "помпа" для перекачування крові  :)

Comment: Ще може бути варіант тлумачення, коли контекст звужується до випадку подружньої зради (або зради чоловіка в стосунках). Тобто, щойно торкнувся принад іншої жінки, як почуття до коханої (= "серце") затьмарюються інстинктами.

Comment: @Gluttton, це ще можна інтерпретувати як «циця в руцю — і всі наміри чоловіка зосереджуються на одному» (тому «серце», бо те, що людина відчуває/хоче _зараз_, зазвичай ототожнюють із серцем). Тобто (невеличке відхилення від напрямку думок Оксани, але в тому ж напрямку), можливо, акцент робиться навіть не на нівелюванні вищих аспектів (розум, моральні якості тощо) (хоча це теж може матися на увазі), а саме на зосередженні уваги на конкретному фізичному (що теоретично може передбачати, а може і не передбачати відключення вищого).

Comment: @Sasha, слушне зауваження. Думаю, все залежить від ширини/глибини контексту.

Comment: Фактично, не вистачає одного — інформації про те, чи є цей вислів прислів'ям (якщо так — то де вживається), чи це винахід Dakh Daughters — а так у коментарях уже відповідь назбиралася.

Comment: @Sasha Якщо орієнтуватись на [визначення](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53407/31949.html), то цей вислів тяжіє до приказки. А приказка може бути й сучасною, і мати конкретного автора, і лише з часом, набувши поширення, стати народною.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, тобто фактично висновок: за структурою тяжіє до приказки, але наскільки часто вживається — невідомо.

Comment: @Sasha, десь так. Можете оформити відповідь, будь ласка, як автор варіанта щодо широкого контекстуального значення?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, спробую пізніше.

Comment: В моєму розумінні "серце (впало) в пуцю/живіт" - це хвилювання. 
Се́рце па́дає (обрива́ється) / впа́ло (обірва́лося) у кого, чиє і без додатка. Хто-небудь завмирає від раптового переляку, тривоги і т. ін. Я прислухавсь. Найменший шелест або стук — і моє серце падає (М. Коцюбинський);
https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8

Comment: @hutorny, _серце впало_ це не скільки _хвилювання_, скільки _[слабке] серце зупинилося_ [від реакцїї на чогось] — найближча аналоґія до фрази [_заціпити уста_](http://sum.in.ua/s/zacipljuvaty). Отже не факт, що саме _впало_. Менї до вподоби думки панї Оксани, особливо тлумачення _подружньої зради_. Бо потїм у словах піснї згадують _бранку_ та _прокльон_ до якоїсь жінки.

Comment: @Follower, так, я прослухала пісню, на яку посилається автор запитання, а потім прочитала текст (бо не все зрозуміло зі співу) і схиляюсь до думки, що в цьому контексті все ж у вузькому значенні, а не в широкому, яке пропонує Sasha. Утім його думка видається мені цілком слушною, бо широкий контекст можливий, що не заперечує вузького.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Розмовне слово «пуця» має різні значення (якби це було щось однозначно непристойне, то його не використовували б як ім'я/прізвисько, але ми бачимо, наприклад, у Валерія Шевчука в декількох творах персонажа *[баба Пуця](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%86%D1%8F%22+OR+%22%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%86%D1%8F%22)*).

Але зокрема воно використувується, як евфемізм на позначення чоловічого статевого органа. Приклади та джерела:

- Леся Ставицька, «Українська мова без табу. Словник нецензурної лексики та її відповідників. Обсценізми, евфемізми, сексуалізми» (2008, Київ, «Критика», 456 с.): «Чоловічий статевий орган: <…> пуц, пуцак, пуцалін, пуцилина, пуцка, пуцлик, пуцька, пуцько, пуцюрина, пуця…» ([ст. 425](http://padaread.com/?book=54260&pg=422); дякую Oksana Gubrenko за хороше джерело).
- Приказка: «Скільки вовка не годуй, а у медведя пуця більша і дупа ширша» (наприклад, [тут](http://www.bukinfo.com.ua/show/news?lid=65540); дякую Artemix за цінний коментар).
- Фраза Ілони з книги Романа Кухарчука «Муха з цукром» (2003), що випадково побачила знайомого голим: «Та пуця у нього нівроку — ніжна і рожевенька — в головці» ([ст. 100](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%86%D1%8F+%D1%83+%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83+%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%96+%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%86%D1%96")).

Саме в цьому значенні вжите це слово і тут.

А всю фразу можна зрозуміти таким чином: коли чоловік торкається жіночих принад, то його наміри зосереждуються на одному… Oksana Gubrenko в коментарі інтерпретувала це як затьмарення розуму/почуттів тілесними інстинктами (що ця фраза доречна, наприклад, у випадку подружньої зради; що частковим аналогом є «думати не головою, а одним місцем»). По-моєму, таке застосування можливе, але не єдине можливе (сама фраза акцентує увагу на зосередженні намірів в певному напрямі; це часто супроводжується відкиданням всього іншого: розуму, моралі тощо — а теоретично може і не супроводжуватися; тобто, на мою думку, на відміну від «думати не головою, а одним місцем», вислів «циця в руцю, а серце — в пуцю» не має чисто негативної конотації, а показує життя як воно є).

Ця фраза за своєю структурою тяжіє до приказки. Але наскільки часто вона вживається (чи широкий ареал її застосування, чи її використовують виключно в оточенні автора слів пісні) — невідомо.

Comment: [Леся Ставицька. Українська мова без табу. Словник нецензурної лексики та її відповідників: Обсценізми, евфемізми, сексуалізми. 456 с. Київ: Критика, 2008.](http://padaread.com/?book=54260&pg=422)

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, о, супер!